# React Native - set order for two functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm new at React Native so I apologize in advance.
 I have a function called setAllComments() which called from componentDidMount. 
This function does AsyncStorage.setItem() and I want this function to be finished before the call for the other function - getComments(), 
(That does AsyncStorage.getItem()).

The problem is that the getComments() function is executed before setAllComments() function is finished.
 
I tried to solve it with callback function but that stuck my application.

Anyone knows how to set order for these two function?

```js
 async componentDidMount() {

        this.setAllComments();

      }

   
  setAllComments = () => {
    console.log("setAllComments function!");
    fetch(URL + "/CommentsList2", {
      body: null,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(commentsResult => {
        console.log("function setAllComments - before comments parse");
        AsyncStorage.setItem("@Project:comments", commentsResult.d);
        console.log("finished setItem");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .then(this.getComments());
  };

  async getComments() {
    console.log("entered getCommens");
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("@Project:comments").then(value => {
      let commentsList = JSON.parse(value);
      this.setState({ comments: commentsList });
      console.log(this.state.comments, "getComments - Player with comments");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple issues w/ your approach.

First. `AsyncStorage` is well async

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("@Project:comments", commentsResult.d);
console.log("finished setItem"); // not true
```

You need to return a promise to keep promise chain

```
  .then(commentsResult => {
    console.log("function setAllComments - before comments parse");
    return AsyncStorage.setItem("@Project:comments", commentsResult.d);
  }) 
  .then(() => console.log("finished setItem");) // now it is more likely :)
```

Then `.then(this.getComments());` you are immediatelly calling the function should be

```
.then(() => this.getComments());
```

And finally `setState` is also async (but atm it doesn't return a promise). So you'd need to pass a callback.

```
this.setState(
  { comments: commentsList },
  () => console.log(this.state.comments, "getComments - Player with comments")
);
```

Also you are mixing `async/await` w/ a bunch of `then/catch` stick to one approach through out your code (at least within a function :))

Comment: Thanks Yury, that did the work. so I can set multiple functions one after the other with this .then(() => this.function()); code ?

Comment: @sup.DR Glad I could help :)

Comment: " I can set multiple functions one after the other with this .then(() => this.function()); code " you can. Assuming functions return promises. But `async/await` provides more readable way to orchestrate  asynchronous code. You could do `await func1(); await func2()`

Answer (score 1):

For being new you are doing great using asyn, but that's not the way async is supposed to work. async has an awesome feature or "word" to work with, it's called "await", exactly what you want. It awaits an async function and there is no need to use ".then()"

Your function with async should be like

```
 async componentDidMount() {

        await this.setAllComments();
        await this.getComments()
      }


  setAllComments = async () => {
    //console.log("setAllComments function!");
    var fetchresult = await fetch(URL + "/CommentsList2", {
      body: null,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
    fetchresult = await fetchresult.json()
    //console.log("function setAllComments - before comments parse");
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@Project:comments", fetchresult.d).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      })
    //console.log("finished setItem")
  };

  async getComments() {
    //console.log("entered getCommens");
    let commentsList = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@Project:comments")
       commentsList = JSON.parse(Comments)
      this.setState({ comments: commentsList });
      //console.log(this.state.comments, "getComments - Player with comments");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ValdaXD

Comment: Sorry @VladaXD but now I cant see the comments due to this line - `fetchresult = await fetchresult.json()`  that cane instead of this code - `.then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })`

Comment: Thats weird, did you already did a console log after ´await fetchersult.json()´. Are you sure that fetchresult.d is a string?, if not, try JSON.stringify(fetchresult.d) instead bacause Asyncstorage only supports strings

Comment: @VladaXD I just send to the AsyncStorage the data I receive. no need to JSON.stringify it (it will make an error too). and this is how the function work. The code  `.then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })`  only check if the object received is a json.

Comment: @sup.DR , res=>returnres.json() is not checking if the object is a json, is converting the object into a json and returning it in "commentsResult". Try to use a try/catch block in async setitem  `try {await AsyncStorage.setItem("@Project:comments", fetchresult.d)}catch(error){}` to see if it works, it's very weird but without knowing the original commentsResult i can´t do anything else ;-;